# Как воспроизвести поток M3U8

Tags: javascript, html

Есть плеер он хорошо воспроизводит потоки, но с конкретно этот не воспроизводит :http://persik.by/stream/975/377885/34.m3u8
К слову расширение для Google chrome "Play HLS M3u8" отлично справляется с потоками такого вида.
Вот плеер который я использую

```
link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<video id='hls-example'  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="400" height="300" controls>
<source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://wms.shared.streamshow.it/tvrs/tvrs/playlist.m3u8">
</video>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.14.1/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>
<script>
var player = videojs('hls-example');
player.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Что значит не воспроизводит? Какие ошибки в js-консоли выдаёт?

Comment: мне не нравятся относительные пути в файле.

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего проблема расширения, которое не смогло декодировать его. Попробуйте плеер VLC, т.к. скорее всего он умеет распознавать его.